# C++ Google test - exporting additional information like 'author' and 'project' to XML report

Tags: c++, xml, report, googletest

I am using the output parameter of google test like

> --gtest_output=xml:Reports\fooReport.xml

However some XML attributes like author and project won´t be exported as the tool *gtest2html* might expect.
Is there a property like 'author' available in gtest at all? If so, where would I assign it?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

In GoogleTest, those fields that you see in `gtest2html` like 'author', 'project', etc. are not available in the xml output by default. Those are custom field expected to be found by `gtest2html`.

However, you can add them to the same xml element using [RecordProperty](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#logging-additional-information) function provided by GoogleTest.

The final section of the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#logging-additional-information) explains:

> Calling RecordProperty() outside of the lifespan of a test is allowed. If it's called outside of a test but between a test suite's SetUpTestSuite() and TearDownTestSuite() methods, it will be attributed to the XML element for the test suite. If it's called outside of all test suites (e.g. in a test environment), it will be attributed to the top-level XML element.

So, in order to make your xml output compatible with `gtest2html`, you need those fields in the outermost xml element (which has the tag "testsuites").

### Solution

So, in main or in a [test environment](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#global-set-up-and-tear-down) (you don't have to use one, but it is strongly recommended in the documentation), before any test is started, you need to add below call:

```
::testing::Test::RecordProperty ("project", "MyProject");
```

This will then add this to the xml output:

```
<testsuites ... project="MyProject" name="AllTests">
```

(I know it is quite late as an answer, but hopefully this will help someone)